# ComboBox and TextBox with Same Functions

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio, combobox

Good day To All, i was wondering is there any possibility

Winform Items

A.) 1~5 ComboBox

B.) 1~5 Textbox for Time (i'll identify them for example as txtTime1 ~ txtTime5)

C.) 1~5 Textbox for Amount (i'll identify them for example as txtAmount1 ~ txtAmount5)

Items 1 ~ 5 (ComboBox 1-5 , txtTime 1-5, txtAmount 1-5) will do the same Functions.

A.)

```
if (combobox1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Regular")
    {
        x = 1.25;
    }
else if (combobox1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Double")
    {
        x = 2;
    }
 // Same Codes for ComboBox 2~5
```

B.)Textbox "txtTime(s)" will hold a TextChange Event fetching values of our said comboBoxes

```
if (txtTime.Text.Lenght > 0)
    {
    // Item Letter "C"
    // value of "x" is equal to the above item
    txtAmount.Text = (double.Parse(txtTime.Text) * x).ToString();
    }
```

i just need a quick idea on how will i make this work

Thank You in Advance

Edit*

All i can think of is calling them 1 by 1 just a quick code

```
private Method1()
{ double x,base;
  if (combobox1 = "Regular")
    { x = base * 1.25; }

  if (combobox2 = "Regular")
    { x = base * 1.25; }
      // so on
 return x;
}

private txtTime1_TextChange(Event ****)
  { 
    if (txtTime1.Text.Lenght > 0)
      { txtAmount1.Text = (Method1() * double.Parse(txtTime1.Text)).ToString();}


private txtTime2_TextChange(Event ****)
    { 
     if (txtTime2.Text.Lenght > 0)
      { txtAmount2.Text = (Method1() * double.Parse(txtTime2.Text)).ToString();}

    // and so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a method as your controls event handler .Each event handler has a sender argument that represent the control that the event has fired for.
You can have a event handler like this :

```
public ComboBoxEventHandler(object sender,EventArgs args)
{
var comboBox=sender as ComboBox;
if(comboBox==null) return;
if (comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Regular")
    {
        x = 1.25;
    }
else if (comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Double")
    {
        x = 2;
    }
}}
```

You can do the same thing for other controls.

**UPDATE**

To make things easier to maintain you can have a class that contains corresponding controls and their behaviors then you can add your controls dynamically to your form without having to repeat yourself or you can add more rows to your form very easily .Take something like this for example:

```
public class RowController
{
public ComboBox Rate{get;private set;}
public TextBox Hours{get;private set;}
public TextBox Amount{get;private set;}

public RowController(ComboBox rate,TextBox hours,TextBox amount)
{
Rate=rate;
Hours=hours;
Hours.TextChange+=OnHoursChanged;
Amount=amount;
}

private void OnHoursChanged(object sender,EventArgs args)
{
 if (Hours.Text.Length > 0)
      { Amount.Text = (GetRate() * double.Parse(Hours.Text)).ToString();}
}

private double GetRate()
{
if (Rate.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Regular")
    {
        return 1.25;
    }
else if (Rate.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Double")
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
}
```

Then you can define RowControllers in your form like this :

```
var row1=new RowController(comboBox1,txtTime1,txtAmount1);
```

and each controller will do its job by its own.